# How to merge two gits in one

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to push my project to github...

First I set up the server and created a git for it. Then I add a new folder called client, with all frontend on it, and I init another git on this folder. Not sure if I have done the right thing, but...

How can I push all files from my project to repo as if I had only one git initialized?

Comment: Well, you could move the entire client folder inside the server folder (or vice-versa), assuming this is really what you want to do.

Comment: Do you want to keep separate histories for the server and the client? If yes, then you should have a look at [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). If not, you can just commit the `client` folder in the `server` repository.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of initialising separate git repos in the client folder & server folder, you better have these folders in a main folder named `website` and initialise a git repo in that and then push everything from there to your remote repository.

```
|-website
  |-server
  |-client
```